# Unit analysis of classical equations, and why charge and mass may be manifestations of the same thing?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, coulombs-law

Consider Newtons force for universal gravitation,
$$F_g=G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}.$$
Nothing new here, but bare with me. This is a strange idea, hard to articulate adequately without a greater understanding of physics which I do not afford, but is there any merit to conclusions we can draw from the unit analysis of this equation when letting $G=1$?

That is to say, suppose $G$ is unitless; just a conversion factor consequential of our unit system and that such an equation really does tell us about some subtle nature of units. To see what I mean, follow me with this example:

Converting this into an expression of units, we find

$$|M||L||T|^{-2}=|M|^2|L|^{-2}\implies |L|^3=|M||T|^2,$$

Now, to me, length and time are quite meaningful units to me. I could not fathom how either could be dependent on some other (more fundamental) units. Mass however, has always been a unit which puzzles me, and feels like it is constructed from other more fundamental units.

With the above equation, (under our controversial assumption), we find
$$|M|=\frac{|L|^3}{|T|^2},$$
that is, $\text{Mass} = \text{Volume per Time per Time}$. Strangely, this seems rather meaningful. I could certainly imagine mass as a resultant property of something to do with volume and a rate of change of said volume.

> Does this unit analysis have any merit or deeper meaning, or am I just mad?

---

**Furthermore,** it would seem that each (albeit classical) equation for the fundamental forces, yields additional definitions of units, under similar assumptions. For example, Coulomb's Law
$$F_e=k_e\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}\text{, yields }|M||L||T|^{-2}=|Q|^2|L|^{-2}\implies |M||L|^3=|Q|^2|T|^2,$$
when $k_e=1$.

Much like mass, charge too puzzles me as seemingly a non-fundamental unit. Thus we could deduce that
$$|Q|^2=\frac{|M||L|^3}{|T|^2},$$
which when combined with our previous equation for mass, yields
$$|Q|^2=\frac{|L|^6}{|T|^4}\implies |Q|=\frac{|L|^3}{|T|^2}.$$
Hence, $\text{Charge} = \text{Volume per Time per Time}$.

> Could this be a hint that charge and mass are manifestations of the same thing, exhibited in different ways?

Answer (score 1):

The units in physics basically means *"we have n times the amount of this quantity as that thing right there has"*. If you are interested in weight or length of some object, you take some reference object and look how much more times of the same quantity yours have. This of course assumes there is some well defined procedure for comparison.

In the gravitational law, we have three quantities, each having their own object/process used for comparison. If we measure time, we need some standard periodical process. If we measure length, we need, for example, some standard rod and if we measure weight, we need, for example, some standard stone.

In your example of setting $G=1$ you made a constraint on which objects/processes you can choose. Either you can choose length/time freely and then you are constrained to look for a stone that produces $G=1$ in the gravitational law, or you can choose weight/time freely and then look for appropriate rod, or you can choose weight/length freely and look for some appropriate periodic process.

But strictly speaking, the unit of mass did not go away. The $G$ still has a unit of $[M]^{-1}[L]^3[T]^{-2}$, it just has a numerical value of 1.

To be able to declare that mass unit is somehow related to time/length units, you would need to find a physical process, which will uniquely fix the stone given the length/time. Length of course makes preference for objects of unit volume, the time will then, through requirement $G=1$, choose the stone of one particular density. So we used gravitational law to find a preferred object given some arbitrary units of length/time. This will be an object of volume of $1[L]^3$ with density $\rho = \frac{K}{G}$ with $K=1[T]^{-2}$

The similar reasoning happens with charge. We already fixed our stone by requirements of volume and density, now we need to fix it further with how much charge it contains. So our preferred object will be given by certain volume as fixed by choice of length, certain density as fixed by gravitational law and certain charge as fixed by coulomb's law.

Does this mean, that

> charge and mass are manifestations of the same thing, exhibited in different ways?

Well, no. Given some mass, you cannot determine how much charge is there, it depends on the composition of the material in question. We needed additional constrain of coulomb law to relate mass and charge, without it, they are not related. To have a relation between mass and charge, the coulomb law and gravitational laws would have to be somehow related. As far as we know, they are not.

For contrast, electric and magnetic fields are connected together by Maxwell equations and both are just different views on one fundamental field. When you look at charged particles and magnets with neutral charge, it might seem like they are independent phenomena with their own independent sources. But it turns out, that magnetic field is generated by a moving charge, so there is indeed a deep connection between charge as source of electric field, and magnetic dipole moment as source of magnetic field.

There is one more question to consider. We made a choice for density and charge using gravitational law and coulomb law. But these two laws do not constitute entirety of physics in the universe. So the natural question is, whether the rest of the physics also leads to these same choices (or whether it is indifferent to it).